# Video set to start at a point in time - current frame not displayed

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video

I am looking to include a video on a web page in multiple instances, each starting at different points in time. I was able to achieve this so that it works on (recent) desktop browsers as well as IOS, but there remains one issue: on the IOS version, the videos do not display with the current frame when the page is loaded. In the desktop browsers, the videos display with the correct current frame.

I would like to use the frames themselves and avoid using the "poster" attribute if possible.

Below is my code - any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

mrwassen

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

<video id="vid1" width="500" controls="" >
       <source src="media/ak_video.mp4"> 
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video id="vid2" width="500" controls="" >
       <source src="media/ak_video.mp4"> 
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script>
var vid1 = document.getElementById("vid1");
var vid2 = document.getElementById("vid2");

if (iOS() == 1) {
  vid1.addEventListener("canplay",function() { this.currentTime = 22;});
  vid2.addEventListener("canplay",function() { this.currentTime = 50;});
  } 
else 
{  
vid1.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {this.currentTime = 22; }, false);
vid2.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {this.currentTime = 50; }, false);
}

function iOS() {
  var iDevices = [
    'iPad Simulator',
    'iPhone Simulator',
    'iPod Simulator',
    'iPad',
    'iPhone',
    'iPod'
  ];
  if (!!navigator.platform) {
    while (iDevices.length) {
      if (navigator.platform === iDevices.pop()){ return 1; }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
</script> 

  </body>
</html>
```